# My Batch script is not working On the Informatica Server ..But working on my Local machine

Tags: command-line, batch

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
echo print this line
set "firstLineReady="
(
    for /F "eol=$ delims=" %%a in (DCRs_*.csv) DO (
        if defined firstLineReady (echo()
        set "firstLineReady=1"
        <nul set /p "=%%a"
    )
) > NewFile.csv
echo I am done 
Type NewFile.csv > DCRs_*.csv
del NewFile.csv
```

I am trying to remove the Last blank line which gets generated by the Informatica Target Flat file.

Please help me with the correct solution, the above script is working on local system but not on Informatica Command Task (only thing its print is the Echo command).

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the server?

Comment: Yes , I do ,,  Imean the Informatica User have ..

Answer (score -2):

Run it under session task as  pre-session or post session command instead of command task

Comment: Can you provide more information as to why the asker should do so?